# A web based phone app with online and local html files

Tags: android, html, magento, web

Hello i am working on a mobile magento theme. What i am looking is to embed or either cache the html, css and javascript files (do not know which is better!) to the application (local storage on phone) and retrieve the product catalog and related pictures from the database and online servers

My intention is to make the app have minimum load on startup and shows as normal native apps

Can you give some guidelines and routine to do so .
Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either give PhoneGap a shot (http://www.phonegap.com), or try it yourself, since PhoneGap is nothing more than some small libraries to make native function (notifications, vibrating etc.) available for JavaScript calls.

If you just want to wrap your site into a native app, you can just put it inside a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), which runs exactly like the native Android browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your html, css and js files to create an android app then the easiest way to attempt this is http://phonegap.com/

However, I would strongly urge you to build a native app (on Android) as Phonegap comes with tons of problems and less support.